# ScrollView and viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

Here is context for my question, this is an optional read:

> I have to develop an app for a
>   school project. At the end of the year some people I don't know will
>   listen to me presenting my app, and review my presentation and my app
>   (note that they will probably not be app developers, they are usually
>   IT professors) (note also that I'm allowed to ask for help to anybody,
>   and I can use internet since I do this mostly on my "free time")
>
> So since October I'm developing my app, that takes a lot of time
>   because this is my first app. And here comes the issue:

My app is a giant Scroll view with 5 NavigationsControllers, each containing a ViewController. These ViewControllers sometimes have buttons that leads to an other ViewController. The problem is when I use these buttons, and another view controller is displayed, when I swipe right or left the ScrollView scrolls and another ViewController from the scrollView is displayed. I don't want this to happen because most of the time the ViewController displayed after the tap on a button is not meant to stay, it's generally a form to send data to the server.

As I think this is difficult to understand, you can download the project on [Github](https://www.github.com/nommis/gsb-app)

Is there a way for me to disable scroll on chosen ViewControllers? or should I change everything to avoid using a ScrollView?

Bonus question:
Is it a really really bad idea to make an app this way, or did I just miss something?

Thanks for your help!